# Is it possible to set Normalized IOPS size in Hyper-V without SOFS/CSV/S2D?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, storage

For each hard disk attached to vm in hyper-v it's possible to set a maximum number of normalized iops.

By default normalized iops size on Hyper-V is 8K.

Is it possible to change this normalized iops size in some way ? Maybe using registry setting ?

I am aware that it's possible to change a normalized iops size when using Storage QOS Policies with SOFS/CSV/S2D, however I am looking for a possibility to change a normalized iops size without using any of these.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-qos/storage-qos-overview

**Step-by-Step Guide**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn282276%28v%3dws.11%29

**To configure a virtual hard disk for Storage Quality of Service**

You can configure the Storage QoS parameters for the bandwidth on the virtual hard disk of your virtual machine using the following procedure.

1. In Server Manager, point to Tools, and then click Tools.
2. Point to Hyper-V Manager and then click Hyper-V Manager.
3. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Hyper-V Manager
4. In the Action pane, click Settings.
5. Double click SCSI Controller.
6. Point to SCSI Controller and then click SCSI Controller.
7. Click Hard Drive. You will see Hard Drive settings displayed in the 
   right pane.
8. To the left of the Hard Drive icon, click “+”.
9. Click Advanced Features.
10. In the Advanced Features pane, click Enable Quality of Service management.
11. Enter Maximum IOPS values. The default value is 0..
12. Enter your Minimum IOPS values. The default value is 0.
13. Click OK.

Comment: This instruction is for setting max/min iops per vmharddisk, however it doesn't mention changing of the Normalized IOPS size which by default is 8K.